# Executing SQL query

Tags: sql, odoo

So I'm migrating my modules from 7 to 8 and I have a problem with the queries.

I have my query like this:

```
SELECT sum(product_qty) FROM stock_move WHERE state NOT IN ('cancelled', 'done') AND product_id = %s AND purchase_line_id IS NOT NULL;
```

And then to execute that query I have:

```
self._cr.execute(sql, (product,))
```

And to fetch the data I have:

```
amount = self._cr.fetchone()
```

It doesn't fetch any data, why is this? When I run the query in the console it works as intended.

Comment: First, test your query in PgAdmin interface. 
Second, in the new v8 API the database cursor is contained in the environment, and can be accessed like this: `self.env.cr`
So your line should look something like this:
`self.env.cr.execute("SELECT sum(product_qty) FROM ...yaddayadda")`

Comment: @ChiruConstantin-Alexandru The cursor is also contained in self if you have api.multi for example. The mistake I made was that I used api.model which doesn't have a cursor.

Answer (score 3):

So v7 and v8 Api is quite different in their behaviours, in v7 you use to have cr as method `params` so you can directly say cr.execute and it works, but in v8 cr is part of executing `[environment][1]` variable which stores various contextual data used by the ORM and cr is part of it. Now, as 'cr' is part of `environment` and `environment` , variable named `env`, is part of self you have to pull `cr` from `env`, so syntax will be :

`self.env.cr.execute("<yoursql>")`

This will perform he sql injection.

But be careful of v7 and v8 Syntax mix and match behaviour of v8 framework. If you still using old API methois with cr, uid, ids and context param your cr is direct then part of self.

Thanks